# SELECT GROUP_BY and GROUP_CONCAT same values in a table only if one of the values has a NULL field

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat

I have a table full of names and addresses. I want to combine (group_concat) all the rows that have the same values for city state and name, but only if one of the addresses is a NULL value. For example I might have this table:

```
name     |    addr    |  city  | state  | phone 

jon snow | 123 got st |  la    | CA     | 1234567890
jon snow | NULL       |  la    | CA     | 1225556789
walker   | 777 diff ln|  la    | CA     | 4556678899
walker   |456 crown rd|  la    | CA     | 33344455566
```

I would like the outcome to be:

```
name     |    addr    |  city  | state  | phone

jon snow | 123 got st |  la    | CA     | 1234567890,1225556789
walker   | 777 diff ln|  la    | CA     | 4556678899
walker   |456 crown rd|  la    | CA     | 33344455566
```

Currently I am using the following command:

```
SELECT name, group_concat(distinct(addr)) as addr, city, state, group_concat(distinct phone) as phone from got_table group by name, city, state having count(*) >1;
```

This ends up combining all addresses with the same name, city, state even if there are two non-null addresses. The outcome of the above statement looks like below:

```
name     |    addr                  |  city  | state  | phone

jon snow | 123 got st               |  la    | CA     | 1234567890,1225556789
walker   | 777 diff ln, 456 crown rd|  la    | CA     | 4556678899, 33344455566
```

Is there a way to only combine if one of the row's addresses are NULL and only perform this group_concat if there are only 2 rows that match.

Comment: what do you want to happen if there is three rows with the same city and state, and one of them has a `null` value in `addr`? Should both of the rows with a non-null `addr` be returned, or only one of them?

Comment: Additionally, which row of the 2 non-null `addr` should the `phone` from the null `addr` row go on? IE, if there was also this row `jon snow | 425 Kings way |  la    | CA     | 1234567899` in you data, what should the results be?

Comment: I think only combine if there are only 2 addresses, one that is null and one that is not null @AsherMaximum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to group by `CASE WHEN` with subquery to make it.

check `addr` column whether `NULL` get.

1. `addr` IS NULL get `MAX` value or your expect group by concat value.
2. `addr` IS NOT NULL get `addr`

look like this.

```
CREATE TABLE got_table(
   name varchar(50),
   addr varchar(50),
  city varchar(50),
    state varchar(50),
    phone varchar(50)
); 


insert into got_table values ('jon snow','123 got st'  ,'la', 'CA', '1234567890');
insert into got_table values ('jon snow',NULL          ,'la', 'CA', '1225556789');
insert into got_table values ('walker','777 diff ln' ,'la', 'CA'  , '4556678899');
insert into got_table values ('walker','456 crown rd','la', 'CA'  , '33344455566');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT name,
       case when addr is null then
       (
         SELECT MAX(tt.addr) 
         FROM got_table tt
         WHERE t1.name = tt.name 
         and t1.city = tt.city 
         and t1.state = tt.state
       ) else addr end as address,
       city, 
       state, 
       group_concat(distinct phone) as phone 
from got_table t1
group by name, city, state,address
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8bcf00/1/0)**:

```
|     name |      address | city | state |                 phone |
|----------|--------------|------|-------|-----------------------|
| jon snow |   123 got st |   la |    CA | 1225556789,1234567890 |
|   walker | 456 crown rd |   la |    CA |           33344455566 |
|   walker |  777 diff ln |   la |    CA |            4556678899 |
```